# Rotate along a single axis of an empty

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]
As you can see I'm rotating these points around the empty. Currently, I'm using manual entry in a Combine xyz node to rotate it along the global Z axis.

What I want to achieve is the same rotation but in the local Z axis of the empty. It feels like a very easy solution but I seem to have blacked out on it. help me, please

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't seem to understand what you are actually trying to do... or if I understand it, I don't see what your problem is. The _Object Info_ node has a _Rotation_ output, why not use that? And if you want to make sure only the Z rotation is used no matter how the empty is rotated on other axes, plug the _Rotation_ first into a _Separate XYZ_ node and only connect the Z output with a _Combine XYZ_ node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align a single vector with the Empty's rotation first and then use the former as a rotation axis. The simple setup is shown on the figure bellow:

[image]

**Note:** If you need the center of the Empty to be the center of rotation - connect the Control Object's **Location** property to the **Center** property of the second Vector Rotate node

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what he wants... to me it reads as if instead of manually entering a value like he does in the _Combine XYZ_ node he wants to use the Z rotation of the empty to control it, while in your solution he still has to manually change the _Angle_ in the second _Vector Rotate_ node.

Comment: So either he wants something very simple - like what I suggest in my comment under the question - or probably you could plug the _Rotation_ output of the _Object Info_ node into a _Separate XYZ_ node and use the Z output for the _Angle_ on the _Vector Rotate_ node.

Comment: You can start with his set up to see how the set position node behaves. Then rotate the empty so its local Z axis is not aligned with world Z axis and try to rotate the mesh(points) around the new local Z axis. If you have a better solution you should definitely post it s an answer.

Comment: Nothing against your answer, as I said if you just connect the empty's Z to the angle... because it does not seem as if he wants to manually enter a value. Apart from all that - I'm not quite sure what he actually wants exactly, so I'm not going to ask my crystal ball for that just to come up with a different answer when yours is already working fine...

Comment: Yes, the question is not very well stated. From my understanding he still wants to manually rotate the points but around the Empty's Local Z axis (ex. points orbiting  the Empty's Z axis but slightly tilted, like a galaxy). Let's wait for Anurag's response and improve upon it.